# I'm trying to find out what it's called

Tags: javascript

Is there an easier way to achieve this in JavaScript? For example without creating a function? And what is it called?

Thank you

```js
function testmulti(id,name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}    
 
var test3 = new Array();
test3=new testmulti("4","toto2");

console.log(test3);
```

Comment: well ... `= new Array();` is redundant, since `test3=new testmulti("4","toto2");` replaces the Array

Comment: You want to know what what is called?

Comment: ignoring the `= new Array()` (because your code does ignore it anyway) read all about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Answer (score 1):

It's called an object. In variable `test3` there is object and it can be created explicit or by function. In my example you can create only single object. In your example you have builder pattern, which allows you to create multiple, different objects.

```js
 
test3 = {
    id: '4',
    name: 'toto2'
};

console.log(test3);
```

Comment: not really the same thing ... since test3 is just an `object` here, as opposed to a `testmulti` in the OP's code

Comment: Method is different. The result is the same.

Comment: I'd say similar, not same :p `test3.constructor` for example ...

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript ES6 onwards, you can create a class for an entity like this:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

And then, create an object of the class like below:

```
const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);
```